# Program keeps looping

Tags: c

For some reason that I can't comprehend ,this program keeps looping when I execute it in the `CMD`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char array [] = {'b','f','r','o','a','u','v','t','o','\0'};
    int grootteArray = sizeof(array);
    int grootteChar = sizeof(char);               
    int lengteArray = grootteArray / grootteChar;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < lengteArray + 1; i + 2) {
        printf("%c", array[i]);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: In addition to all these answers, be careful because sizeof(array) will always be 4. To get the length of the string use strlen() from string.h.

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc That is not correct.sizeof(array)== 10 http://ideone.com/fork/agvGKv

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc, you really should read about arrays and pointers, they are not the same in C.

Comment: Whoops my bad. Thought it was sizeof(char *).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your counter variable remains the same after each loop. You need to increase it by assigning the new value:

```
for (i=0; i<lengteArray+1; i=i+2) //change to this
```

Answer (score 7):

Because `i` never changes. You should assign `i + 2` to `i`:

```
for (i=0; i<lengteArray+1; i = i + 2) {
                             ↑
```

The way you wrote it has no effect on the value of `i`, it just calculates `i + 2` and does nothing with this value.

You're getting infinite loop because `i` is set to `0` and it's always `0`.. So once `i < legteArray + 1`, it'll remain like that.

Comment: Doesnt the i+2 count?

Comment: @BURNS:- No that is not the syntxx for the for loop!

Comment: What do you mean by *count*?

Comment: `i + 2` never changes the original variable. It just computes the result and discards it.

Comment: Thank you :) I meant it as in counting up ,i+2 for each loop.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is not modifying in you loop. Also `i < lengteArray + 1` will lead you to print garbage value and undefined behavior.

```
for (i = 0; i < lengteArray; i++){
    printf("%c", array[i]);
}
```

If you are interested in incrementing `i` by 2 in each iteration then you can use `i += 2`

```
for (i = 0; i < lengteArray; i += 2){
    printf("%c", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: @ComFreek; Actually some people on SO really likes me. Seriously!

Comment: @Kunal:- Even if the original answer was wrong but now since the answer is now changed and is correct you may take down your downvote. Lets try to keep the spirit of SO at its best :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun; Answer was correct. I made presumption that OP wants to increment `i` by 1.

Comment: @Kunal; I am again asking you, what was wrong with that answer?  I edited my answer with previous one. Tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: @haccks Don't worry. Some people have fun when downvoting answers which are actually correct. +1 from me.

Comment: I didn't downvote you man. I just replied to "why it was downvoted".

Comment: @ComFreek I would take back my downvote happily if I had given one. Replying to your query was a bad decision :)

Comment: @Kunal; I never said you downvoted or remove your downvote. I am expecting an explanation for your previous comment.

Comment: @haccks You already said yourself that in your original answer you incremented `i` by 1.

Comment: @ComFreek; I am telling you a truth: On SO there are some ghost souls who came to post and vote up/down by seeing whether question is upvoted/downvoted without thinking over it!! (Believe it or not). And if they are very happy the they will [voted down your answers serially](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2455888/haccks?tab=summary)

Comment: @haccks I know that from my own experience here (not that Kunal is one). Oh, serial downvoting also happened once to me. Report it to team@stackoverflow.com and all reputations will be restored.

Comment: + for informing about array out-of-index problem (specially when string is of even length) Not , `i++` better then `i += 1` and `i += 1` is better then `i = i + 1`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks for adding undefined behavior to the answer :). I think `i++` is better than other two.

Comment: Actually `i += 2` is only option What I means `i += 2` is better then `i = i + 2`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Yes, in this case this is the only option.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `i` is never changed.

try this:-

```
for (i=0; i<lengteArray+1; i = i+2) {
```